# Number of different possible armies in Clash of Clans

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we are given a set of sixteen different units. How many different armies of $200$ units exist ?

In other words, how many $16$-uplets $(c_1, \cdots, c_{16})$ exist such that

- for each $i$, $c_i \in \{0,\cdots,200\}$
- $\sum c_i = 200$

?

Answer (score 2):

The theorem you are looking for is the Stars and Bars theorem, and more info can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)